# Multiple IP addresses on Google Cloud Compute

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, centos7

I'm trying to setup my VM based on CentOS 7 with more than one internal IP address, but it doesn't seem to be as straightforward as Amazon AWS.

Comment: 1. This is not a programming question so is not appropriate for Stackoverflow. 2. What is your specific question? You can't just say "it doesn't work". You need to explain what you have tried and what specific errors you are getting . Once you have a properly thought out question then post in on a relevant site - possibly [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe each Compute VM can only have one internal IP. See the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-instance-ip-addresses

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add internal IP for VM using routes. (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/routes)

Here an example of setting another static internal IP to VM:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#staticnetworkaddress