# How to add extra private IP's to a GCP instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to add multiple routable ip addresses to an ubuntu 14.04 GCP instance.  What is the simplest method for achieving this?

**Note**: External IP addresses are disabled on my gcp instances.

Correct me if I am wrong, but the solution described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979603/multiple-ip-addresses-on-google-cloud-compute) that uses gcloud routes seems to change the network and firewall configuration to add extra IP addresses to instances.  I am looking for a different solution.

1. I would like to add IP addresses to instances without changing the networks or firewalls of a gcp project at all.
2. I would like to add random available IP addresses on the current network of a gcp instance and avoid manually assigning an IP address or  IP address range to my instances?

I am really looking for a solution that is similar to openstacks `nova add-fixed-ip` command that does just this. You can find a description of `nova add-fixed-ip` here: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/65198/how-to-assign-static-private-ip-address-to-a-running-guest-vm/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple IP addresses on Google Cloud Compute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979603/multiple-ip-addresses-on-google-cloud-compute)